# Disable swipe between tabs

Tags: nativescript

In the development of my application, I use a tabview with three different tabs. By default, you can switch between tabs either by clicking on the tab or by swiping horizontally. Since I'd like to add a [sidedrawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui) in one tab specifically (is it possible ?), I'd like to disable the swiping between the tabs. How can I do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not disable the swiping, but you can handle **selectedIndex** change event of the **TabView**. When you are on a certain tab to call **showDrawer** method, witch will load the **sidedrawer**. You can review my code in github. [sample project](https://github.com/tsonevn/sideDrawer-TabView.git)